Why does passing a variable into a View that is presented using a sheet cause the sheet to be blank?
I am currently making a Calorie Tracking app using Swift, but am having some issues with how different views are presented using sheets when trying to pass a variable have 2 views - my CaloriesView:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct CaloriesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var calsViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    @State private var shouldPresentSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedCategory: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    CurrentCaloriesView(viewModel: calsViewModel)
                    
                    mealSection("Breakfast", foods: calsViewModel.breakfasts)
                    mealSection("Lunch", foods: calsViewModel.lunches)
                    mealSection("Dinner", foods: calsViewModel.dinners)
                    mealSection("Other Food", foods: calsViewModel.otherFoods)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Calories", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await calsViewModel.fetchTodayMacros()
                await calsViewModel.fetchTodayFoodIntake()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentSheet) {
            FoodListView(calsViewModel: calsViewModel)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func mealSection(_ category: String, foods: [(String, Double)]) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(category)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.top)
            
            ForEach(foods.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let food = foods[index]
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text(food.0)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .bold()
                    Text("Weight: \(food.1, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    let currentDate = Date() // Use the current date
                    let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid // Directly using the user ID as we're sure user is logged in
                    
                    do {
                        let macrosDocumentExists = await calsViewModel.doesMacrosDocumentExist(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        if !macrosDocumentExists {
                            try await calsViewModel.createMacrosDocument(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        }
                        
                        let foodIntakeDocumentExists = await calsViewModel.doesFoodIntakeDocumentExist(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        if !foodIntakeDocumentExists {
                            try await calsViewModel.createIntakeDocument(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        }
                        
                        selectedCategory = category
                        shouldPresentSheet = true
                    } catch {
                        print("Error creating documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        // Handle errors, perhaps by showing an alert to the user
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Label("Add Food For \(category)", systemImage: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
}

And my FoodView:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct FoodListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var calsViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    @ObservedObject var foodViewModel = FoodViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(foodViewModel.foods) { food in
                NavigationLink(destination: FoodDetailView(calsViewModel: calsViewModel, food: food)) {
                    Text(food.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Select Food")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                foodViewModel.fetchFoods()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FoodDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var calsViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    var food: Food
    @State private var weight: String = "100"
    @State private var showConfirmation: Bool = false
    @State private var errorMessage: String?
    @ObservedObject var authViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter weight in grams", text: $weight)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            if let weightAsDouble = Double(weight) {
                Text("Calories: \(Double(food.calories) * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") kcal")
                Group {
                    Text("Protein: \(food.protein * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                    Text("Carbs: \(food.carbs * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                    Text("Fat: \(food.fat * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                }
                .font(.headline)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Add Food") {
                Task {
                    let today = Date()
                    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                        errorMessage = "Unexpected error: User ID is not available."
                        return
                    }
                    
                    do {
                        let weightDouble = Double(weight) ?? 100
                        let mealType: MealType = .other // This should be determined or selected by the user
                        print("Adding food with weight: \(weightDouble)") // Debug log
                        try await calsViewModel.addFoodIntakeAndUpdateMacros(userId: userId, date: today, food: food, weight: weightDouble, mealType: mealType)
                        
                        showConfirmation = true
                    } catch {
                        errorMessage = "An unexpected error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                }
            }
            .alert("Food Added", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            } message: {
                Text("Your daily intake has been updated.")
            }

            if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                Text(errorMessage)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("\(food.name) Details")
    }
}

Currently, in FoodDetailsView, the mealType variable that is being saved to the firestore document is hardcoded to be ‘Other Food’, so all of the food, no matter which of the 4 "Add Food For \(category)" buttons I click is being shown in the ‘Other Food’ category
I instead want the food to be saved into the Firestore document with the relevant mealType, depending on which section the button is clicked in
I have tried doing this by passing a mealType variable through when the “Add Food For \(category)" button is clicked, as you can see in the new versions of CaloriesView and FoodView below:
CaloriesView:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct CaloriesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var calsViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    @State private var shouldPresentSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedCategory: String? = nil
    @State private var selectedMealType: MealType? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    CurrentCaloriesView(viewModel: calsViewModel)
                    
                    mealSection("Breakfast", foods: calsViewModel.breakfasts, mealType: .breakfast)
                    mealSection("Lunch", foods: calsViewModel.lunches, mealType: .lunch)
                    mealSection("Dinner", foods: calsViewModel.dinners, mealType: .dinner)
                    mealSection("Other Food", foods: calsViewModel.otherFoods, mealType: .other)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Calories", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await calsViewModel.fetchTodayMacros()
                await calsViewModel.fetchTodayFoodIntake()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldPresentSheet) {
            if let selectedMealType = selectedMealType {
                FoodListView(calsViewModel: calsViewModel, mealType: selectedMealType)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func mealSection(_ category: String, foods: [(String, Double)], mealType: MealType) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(category)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.top)
            
            ForEach(foods.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let food = foods[index]
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text(food.0)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .bold()
                    Text("Weight: \(food.1, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 8)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    let currentDate = Date()
                    let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                    
                    do {
                        let macrosDocumentExists = await calsViewModel.doesMacrosDocumentExist(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        if !macrosDocumentExists {
                            try await calsViewModel.createMacrosDocument(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        }
                        
                        let foodIntakeDocumentExists = await calsViewModel.doesFoodIntakeDocumentExist(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        if !foodIntakeDocumentExists {
                            try await calsViewModel.createIntakeDocument(userId: currentUserId, date: currentDate)
                        }
                        
                        selectedCategory = category
                        selectedMealType = mealType
                        shouldPresentSheet = true
                    } catch {
                        print("Error creating documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Label("Add Food For \(category)", systemImage: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
}

FoodView:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct FoodListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var calsViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    @ObservedObject var foodViewModel = FoodViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var mealType: MealType

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(foodViewModel.foods) { food in
                NavigationLink(destination: FoodDetailView(calsViewModel: calsViewModel, food: food, mealType: mealType)) {
                    Text(food.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Select Food")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                foodViewModel.fetchFoods()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FoodDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var calsViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    var food: Food
    var mealType: MealType
    @State private var weight: String = "100"
    @State private var showConfirmation: Bool = false
    @State private var errorMessage: String?
    @ObservedObject var authViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter weight in grams", text: $weight)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            if let weightAsDouble = Double(weight) {
                Text("Calories: \(Double(food.calories) * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") kcal")
                Group {
                    Text("Protein: \(food.protein * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                    Text("Carbs: \(food.carbs * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                    Text("Fat: \(food.fat * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") g")
                }
                .font(.headline)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Add Food") {
                Task {
                    let today = Date()
                    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                        errorMessage = "Unexpected error: User ID is not available."
                        return
                    }
                    
                    do {
                        let weightDouble = Double(weight) ?? 100
                        print("Adding food with weight: \(weightDouble)") // Debug log
                        try await calsViewModel.addFoodIntakeAndUpdateMacros(userId: userId, date: today, food: food, weight: weightDouble, mealType: mealType)
                        
                        showConfirmation = true
                    } catch {
                        errorMessage = "An unexpected error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                }
            }
            .alert("Food Added", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            } message: {
                Text("Your daily intake has been updated.")
            }

            if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                Text(errorMessage)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("\(food.name) Details")
    }
}

But doing this causes the sheet containing FoodListView to be presented as completely blank, containing not even the ‘Cancel’ button
The original code did not do this - any ideas why? Thanks
Edit - Minimal Reproducible Example:
Data Models:
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Food: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let name: String
    let calories: Int
    let protein: Double
    let carbs: Double
    let fat: Double
}

struct FoodIntake: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var date: Date
    var userId: String
    var food: [FoodArray]?
}

struct FoodArray: Codable {
    var selectionId: String
    var weight: Double
    var foodId: String
    var mealType: String
}

struct DailyMacros: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var userId: String
    var date: Date
    var calories: Int
    var protein: Double
    var carbs: Double
    var fat: Double
}

View Models:
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Combine

class FoodViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foods: [Food] = []

    func fetchFoods() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("food").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching foods: \(error)")
                return
            }

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                print("No foods found")
                return
            }

            self.foods = documents.compactMap { try? $0.data(as: Food.self) }
        }
    }
}

class CaloriesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dailyMacros: DailyMacros?
    private var macrosRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("dailyMacros")
    private var foodIntakeRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("foodIntake")

    func addFoodIntake(userId: String, date: Date, food: Food, weight: Double) async throws {
        let intake = FoodIntake(date: date, userId: userId, food: [FoodArray(selectionId: UUID().uuidString, weight: weight, foodId: food.id ?? "", mealType: "Other")])
        _ = try await foodIntakeRef.addDocument(from: intake)

        let macros = DailyMacros(userId: userId, date: date, calories: food.calories, protein: food.protein, carbs: food.carbs, fat: food.fat)
        _ = try await macrosRef.addDocument(from: macros)
    }
}

Views:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var foodViewModel = FoodViewModel()
    @StateObject var caloriesViewModel = CaloriesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(foodViewModel.foods) { food in
                NavigationLink(destination: FoodDetailView(food: food, caloriesViewModel: caloriesViewModel)) {
                    Text(food.name)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Food List")
            .onAppear {
                foodViewModel.fetchFoods()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FoodDetailView: View {
    var food: Food
    @ObservedObject var caloriesViewModel: CaloriesViewModel
    @State private var weight: String = "100"
    @State private var showConfirmation: Bool = false
    @State private var errorMessage: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter weight in grams", text: $weight)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()

            if let weightAsDouble = Double(weight) {
                Text("Calories: \(Double(food.calories) * weightAsDouble / 100, specifier: "%.2f") kcal")
            }

            Spacer()

            Button("Add Food") {
                Task {
                    do {
                        let userId = "userID" // Replace with actual user ID
                        let date = Date()
                        try await caloriesViewModel.addFoodIntake(userId: userId, date: date, food: food, weight: Double(weight) ?? 100)
                        showConfirmation = true
                    } catch {
                        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
                    }
                }
            }
            .alert("Food Added", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            }

            if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
                Text(errorMessage)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding()
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle(food.name)
    }
}

Main:
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct CaloriesApp: App {
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


Please include a [mre]

try using .sheet(item: ...) to pass the desired item to the sheet view, eg: .sheet(item: $selectedMealType) {...}. Show a minimal code example.

Possible duplicate
